# Power BI - Persist and incrementally add data after refreshing

Tags: powerbi, refresh, azure-application-insights

There is a web application that produces log statements in Azure Application Insights. I want to create a Power BI Dashboard that uses that data to create visualizations. But the data needs to be persisted in Power BI or else I have to query the FULL data each and every time I click on "refresh", which is what is happening right now. That is just too inefficient. I want to retrieve data for the past couple of days and store/persist that data, and incrementally add new data on top of it each time I click on refresh.

I tried implementing Power BI Incremental Refresh, but that is not applicable to this data source apparently.

Is there any way to make Incremental Refresh work, or is there any other alternative for this?

I hope someone can help me out with this one. Thanks.

The query that I generated through Azure Application Insights for Power BI looks as follows:
/*

```
The exported Power Query Formula Language (M Language ) can be used with Power Query in Excel
and Power BI Desktop.
For Power BI Desktop follow the instructions below: 
1) Download Power BI Desktop from https://powerbi.microsoft.com/desktop/
2) In Power BI Desktop select: 'Get Data' -> 'Blank Query'->'Advanced Query Editor'
3) Paste the M Language script into the Advanced Query Editor and select 'Done'
*/


let AnalyticsQuery =
let Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/15a450/query", 
[Query=[#"query"="traces 
",#"x-ms-app"="AAPBI",#"timespan"="PT12H",#"prefer"="ai.response-thinning=true"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}}))
in
Table
in AnalyticsQuery
```

Comment: Incremental Refresh is the easiest solution.  It doesn't require anything special from the data source; you just must integrate the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters into the Power Query.

Comment: Thanks. I did all of that. But 'View Native Query' is greyed out it. And according to microsoft "In the Query Settings pane, when you right-click the last applied step, if the View Native Query option is enabled (not greyed out), then the entire query can be folded.". This means that the query is not foldable, but it needs to be foldable or else Incremental refresh cant work.

Comment: And btw, I created a "Blank Query" to retrieve the data from Azure Application Insights (which works).

Comment: Incremental Refresh (despite some confusing wording in the docs) does not depend on query folding.  The RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters are already injected into your query.  If your query is not foldable _and_ you want to use the "Detect Data Changes" feature, you have to supply a custom change detection query.  Per https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/07/31/custom-queries-for-detect-data-changes-in-power-bi-incremental-refresh/

Comment: So I can ignore the fact that "View Native Query" is greyed out?

Comment: Also, the query I created; I exported that through Azure AI by writing a query in Azure AI, running it and clicking on the export button. That is the query I use in Power BI Blank Query. The export/query contains a "timespan"="P2D". Doesnt that interfere with the RangeStart/RangeEnd? Imagine the timespan to be 2 days, but the RangeEnd to be 10 days for example.

Comment: Definitely will interfere.  You must rewrite the query to use the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters for the TIMESTAMP.  EG `| where TIMESTAMP >= datetime(2022-11-03 00:00:00)`

Comment: Actually, the timespan is used for that?


",#"x-ms-app"="AAPBI",#"timespan"="P2D",#"prefer"="ai.response-thinning=true"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),..............

Comment: This (only part of the query) is generated when I exported my own custom query to use in Power BI. (did that through Azure Application Insights, in the menu it states "export for power bi").

Comment: Please add the whole PQ to your question.  The change needs to be made in the KQL.

Comment: I just added the query as a whole! This is the query in its simplest form (basically I double clicked on the traces table in Azure AI and selected to filter on the past 12 hours, and then I clicked on run and then I exported the query to use in Power BI). So there is no real KQL... I did NOT do something like "traces where message == "test123", its just "traces" and nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a KQL query that uses a date range, like

```
traces 
| where timestamp >=  datetime(2022-11-20 00:00:00) 
| where timestamp < datetime(2022-11-22 00:00:00)
```

Then after exporting to a Power Query, integrate the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters, like this

:

```
let AnalyticsQuery =
let 
    strRangeStart = DateTime.ToText(RangeStart,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),
    strRangeEnd = DateTime.ToText(RangeEnd,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/60845e27-7ed2-42ef-8ade-25a2fe8236ef/query", 
    [Query=[#"query"="traces 
    | where timestamp >= datetime(" & strRangeStart &") 
    | where timestamp < datetime("& strRangeEnd &")
    ",#"x-ms-app"="AAPBI",#"prefer"="ai.response-thinning=true"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
    TypeMap = #table(
    { "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
    { 
    { "string",   Text.Type },
    { "int",      Int32.Type },
    { "long",     Int64.Type },
    { "real",     Double.Type },
    { "timespan", Duration.Type },
    { "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
    { "bool",     Logical.Type },
    { "guid",     Text.Type },
    { "dynamic",  Text.Type }
    }),
    DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
    Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
    ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
    Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
    Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}}))
in
Table
in AnalyticsQuery
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! I will try this tomorrow, and will let you know! :)

Comment: What are the RangeStart and RangeEnd used for? Is the start for "LOAD once" and end for "incrementally add that part of the data"?

Comment: Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview

Comment: I have one more (last, I promise) question and it would really really help me out if I could get an answer!! What happens when I click on refresh at 15:00, will it by default incrementally add data starting from 00:00 that day, or 15:00 the previous day if the refresh date is set to 1 day? And what happens when I click on refresh again, 1 hour later, at 16:00? Does it remember that it already got the data from 15:00 and earlier and that it only needs to add data for the past hour?